# Need crack some files with rar3 hash, can be possible?

Tags: passwords

I am interested in cracking two rar files but it has a long password more than 9 characters and less of 20.

So my question is how much time will take me?

And the password can be any characters so seems probably impossible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's reformulate, by "recover" instead of "crack" to better comply site policies.

First, if those rar files came from the internet you can try to search for passwords as well.
Otherwise, if you can be sure that the password is between 9 and 20 characters than you can try any brutforce capable software (pick one from https://passper.imyfone.com/rar/top-6-free-password-unlocker/), define the most accurate char-set or take all ascii printable characters (there are about 94), set the range from 9 up to 20 and launch it before going to sleep. There will be between 94^9 and 94^20 tries (which is huge).
Let's count simply the IPS of the CPU (just for a very rough estimation):
An Intel Core i7 4770K (4-core) (data taken from here: *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second) does 133740 MIPS. (Knowing it's not accurate alone, probably FLOPS would be more, but it just gives a very rough approach. More on this here: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-the-CPU-performance-MIPS-of-my-computer-Is-there-any-command-windows)
So, I made some calculations on Excel :-) and it turns out:
Considering 1 combination for 1 cycle, it would reach 9 char combinations (94^9) in nearly 50 days. 10 char word is 94 times this, meaning 13 years and so on (because each time the char nbr grows it has to be started over). So it looks like 20 chars combination word would take really forever.

By a AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3990X (64 core)* CPU with 2,356,230 MIPS, and with only 26 characters (say lower case), 9 chars word would take about 2.6 days, a 14 chars word 1 year, and the 20 chars... still probably more than the Sun has to shine.

And there are many other factors and limitations left behind.

Well, I'm far not a specialist, and did this research and calulations only by curiosity.
The result sounds like crasy. And maybe it is.
So all corrections are welcome.